# Trouble inserting array elements into database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having pretty simple bug but I just can't figure out why it happens.I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => Joakim
            [B] => Dzafic
            [C] => joke@gmail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [A] => Jevren
            [B] => Jevrej
            [C] => zidovi@gmail.com
        )

)
```

And I'm trying to insert it into my `MySQL` database table like so:

```
 foreach($sheetData as $rec){
    $result=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `test`(`name`,`surname`,`email`) VALUES
                (
                ".$rec['A'].",
                ".$rec['B'].",
                ".$rec['C']."
                );");
                if(!$result){
                    var_dump($result);
                    die("Something's wrong with query!");
                }else{
                    echo 'Inserted!';
                }

            }
```

But it says: `Something's wrong with query!` and when I do `var_dump($result);` it says: `bool(false)`
Please help me to debug this part of code because I'm pretty stuck with it.

Comment: change `foreach($sheetData as $rec){` to `foreach($sheetData as $key => $rec) {`

Comment: You should use prepared statements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to add single quote `'` values variable should be enclosed by `'` if it contains string:

```
$result=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `test`(`name`,`surname`,`email`) VALUES
                (
                '".$rec['A']."',
                '".$rec['B']."',
                '".$rec['C']."'
                )");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$mysqli->error` to check query error.

Write your code as below:-

```
foreach($sheetData as $rec){
    $result=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `test`(`name`,`surname`,`email`) VALUES
                (
                '{$rec['A']}',
                '{$rec['B']}',
                '{$rec['C']}',
                )");  // typo error here
                if(!$result){
                    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error); // check error
                    var_dump($result);
                    die("Something's wrong with query!");
                }else{
                    echo 'Inserted!';
                }

}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

A little hint for the future, when you have such problems: var_dump($my_query)

Then you see where the syntax error is or what is going wrong there anyway. :-)

Don't forget to escape the value strings.